# csv column values going to new line causing errors loading in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text-processing

I have an issue with csv's that have a split within a column that go to a new line. I can fix the issue manually editing the .csv but there's ~200 files.

The dataset contains more columns and can contain nulls, however the last column always has a value. The issue also only occurs within the same column every time. So I was thinking of finding when the last value was null and then trying to fill the values with .shift() but was hoping for an easier way.

#### view in vscode

```
orderid,fruit,count,person  
3523,apple,84,peter  
2522,green  
grape, 99, mary   
1299, watermelon, 93, paul
```

#### pandas read_csv

```
orderid fruit       count   person
3523    apple       84      peter
2522    green       NaN     NaN
grape   99          mary    NaN
1299    watermelon  93      paul
```

#### wanted columns

```
orderid fruit       count   person
3523    apple       84      peter
2522    green grape 99      mary
1299    watermelon  93      paul
```

Comment: *edit, vscode and notepad++ show similar results.

Comment: how did you get this CSV ? if you created it using python `open()`, `write()` then you should use module `csv` which should write `green  grape` with `" "` to create correct csv data in file. And then pandas would read it correctly.

Comment: Sadly they download like that... I didn't create them.

Comment: I added a section to easily create a DataFrame from all the csv files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fix your files:

- Use `m = re.findall('(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s+\\n[a-zA-Z]', text)` to find cases like `,green  \ngrape`

  - The pattern will find `alpha  \nalpha` and ignore `alpha  \nnumeric`
  - `m` will be a list of all the matches (e.g. `['  \ng']`)
  - `.replace('  \ng', ' g')`, which results with `,green grape`
- Find all of the files with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

  - `.rglob` looks in all subdirectories.  Use `.glob` if all the files are in one directory
  - `pathlib` treats paths like objects instead of strings.  As such, `pathlib` objects have many methods.
  - `.stem` returns the filename
  - `.suffix` returns the file extension (e.g. `.csv`)
- This will not overwrite your existing files.  It will create a new file, adding `_fixed` to the name.

```py
import re
from pathlib import Path

# list of all the files
files = list(Path(r'c:\some_path').rglob('*.csv'))

# iterate through each file
for file in files:

    # create new filename name_fixed
    new_file = file.with_name(f'{file.stem}_fixed{file.suffix}')

    # read all the text in as a string
    text = file.read_text()

    # find and fix the sections that need fixing
    m = re.findall('(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s+\\n[a-zA-Z]', text)
    for match in m:
        text = text.replace(match, f' {match[-1:]}')
    text_list = text.split('\n')
    text_list = [x.strip() for x in text_list]

    # write the new file
    with new_file.open('w', newline='') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        w.writerows([x.split(',') for x in text_list])
```

### Example:

#### With the following content in a `.csv`:

```py
orderid,fruit,count,person  
3523,apple,84,peter  
2522,green  
grape, 99, mary   
1299, watermelon, 93, paul
3523,apple,84,peter  
2522,green  
banana, 99, mary   
1299, watermelon, 93, paul
3523,apple,84,peter  
2522,green  
apple, 99, mary   
1299, watermelon, 93, paul
```

#### New file:

```py
orderid,fruit,count,person
3523,apple,84,peter
2522,green grape, 99, mary
1299, watermelon, 93, paul
3523,apple,84,peter
2522,green banana, 99, mary
1299, watermelon, 93, paul
3523,apple,84,peter
2522,green apple, 99, mary
1299, watermelon, 93, paul
```

### Create DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

new_files = list(Path(f'c:\some_path').glob('*_fixed.csv'))
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in new_files])
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Here's another solution:

A. The logic here is to first find the rows that start with the 4-digit numbers.

B. Once the rows are identified, any row (except the top one: header row)

- that does not have a 4-digit number to start with and
- does not have three separating `','`,

will be appended to the previous row.

C. Finally any white space will be dropped at the end of a line and all the lines are put together to make a single string, which the user could write to a .csv file if he/she wishes to.

D. We load in this string using `io.StringIO` as a dataframe.

### Example-1

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import re

def get_clean_data(lines):
    target_lines = [re.findall('^\d{4}', line) for line in lines]
    target_lines_dict = dict((i, val[0]) if (len(val)>0) else (i, None) for i,val in enumerate(target_lines))

    correct_lines = list()
    line_index = 0
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if i==0:
            correct_lines.append(line.strip())
        if i>0:
            if target_lines_dict[i] is not None:
                correct_lines.append(line.strip())
                line_index +=1
            else:
                correct_lines[line_index] += ' ' + line.strip()                
    correct_lines = [re.sub(',\s*', ', ', line)+'\n' for line in correct_lines]
    ss = ''.join(correct_lines)
    return ss

# Dummy Data
s = """
orderid,fruit,count,person  
3523,apple,84,peter  
2522,green  
grape, 99, mary   
1299, watermelon, 93, paul
"""
lines = s.strip().split('\n')

# In case of a csv file, use readlines:
# with open('csv_file.csv', 'r') as f:
#     lines = f.readlines()

# Get cleaned data
ss = get_clean_data(lines)

# Make Dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(ss), sep=',')
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
   orderid         fruit   count  person
0     3523         apple      84   peter
1     2522   green grape      99    mary
2     1299    watermelon      93    paul
```

### Example-2

Let us now use the following dummy data.

```py
s = """
orderid,fruit,count,person  
3523,apple,84,peter  
2522,green  
grape, 99, mary   
1299, watermelon, 93, paul
3523,apple,84,peter  
2522,green  
banana, 99, mary   
1299, watermelon, 93, paul
3523,apple,84,peter  
2522,green  
apple, 99, mary   
1299, watermelon, 93, paul
"""
```

**Output**:

```
   orderid          fruit   count  person
0     3523          apple      84   peter
1     2522    green grape      99    mary
2     1299     watermelon      93    paul
3     3523          apple      84   peter
4     2522   green banana      99    mary
5     1299     watermelon      93    paul
6     3523          apple      84   peter
7     2522    green apple      99    mary
8     1299     watermelon      93    paul
```